# How can I compute the height of a UIWebview before loading html string into it?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Let's say I have a HTML string and I fix the width of the UIWebview to x.

Is there a way to **compute** the height of the UIWebview before loading html string into it ?

Edit:

And even before creating the UIWebView object.

Comment: `[myWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(startX,startY, width, height)]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need a UIWebview with the content loaded for calculating the height of the content.